# How can I find the voltage in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, superposition

I have to find the voltage \$U_b\$ in this given circuit.

[image]

I already tried it using the superposition principle looking at the circuit with only the voltage source first and then only with the power source, but I do not get the correct result.

\$U_q = 35.1\ \mathrm{V}\$, \$R=32\ \Omega\$, \$I_q=6.9\ \mathrm{A}\$

So far, I have:

1. Looking at the circuit without \$I_q\$:

   $$U_1 = \frac{3R}{6R}\cdot U_q$$
   $$U_2 = -\frac{R}{6R}\cdot U_q$$
2. Looking at the circuit without \$U_q\$:
   $$U_i = 3RI_q$$
   $$U_3 = \frac{3R}{6R}\cdot 3RI_q$$
   $$U_4 = -\frac{R}{6R}\cdot 3RI_q$$
3. $$U_b=U_1+U_3-U_2-U_4$$

Comment: Please post your work so far, so we can correct any mistakes you've made rather than giving you all the answers from scratch.

Comment: The current flows in the opposite direction of the voltage source's arrow.

Comment: @emircg02 Not my question. I wanted to know the polarization of the voltage source. I might take what you wrote to mean the upper end is positive. Or not.

Comment: Oh sorry, it's plus to minus.

Comment: @emircg02 The upper end is positive?

Comment: Yes, but why is that important for this question?

Comment: @emircg02 How did you arrive at your 1. equations? They look wrong. So how did you develop them? What mental steps were applied? (Not just the end of your thinking, but the intermediate steps.)

Comment: @periblepsis You're right, I think my whole approach is wrong. I tried to apply the superposition principle and then do voltage division at the left and right node of U_b.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150798/discussion-between-emircg02-and-periblepsis).

Answer (score 0):

I found Thevenin/Norton Transformations to be useful for many problems like this. But, you should use whatever you are comfortable with.

Always look for shortcuts. The resistor in series with the current source can be removed. The middle 4 resistors are symmetrical, the current will be equal through the 2 legs.

64 ohms is the same as two 128 ohms in parallel. This makes it obvious that the current is split 4 ways in the Norton circuit.

Don't skimp on the drawings. Draw out the two superposition cases, then each can be solved quickly with the shortcuts.

And of course, once you know the current, you can find the voltage on the two Ub nodes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffn3VM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A method that adapts very well to the analysis of the given network is provided by Millman's theorem, as follows:

[image]